# Can you form the sigma algebra generated by a collection of subset always?

Tags: measure-theory

From around 4:00 in [this video](https://youtu.be/z5m6HXKx0Wo?si=r1sKLtNVZpJ8yrno), the creator makes it seem that you can form the smallest sigma-algebra that contains **any** collection of sets by taking intersections of sigma algebras that contain it, and that you can even "use the power set if you want". Why is this possible? Let's say the collection I choose contains a non-measurable set, there should be no sigma algebra that contains it, the power set therefore definitely isn't a sigma-algebra then. Why would I be able to form a sigma algebra from it?

Comment: Although sigma algebras are used at the core of measure theory, they do exist outside of them, and any particular sigma algebra can totally contain non-mesurable sets. Also, the power set is definitely sigma algebra - it satisfies all the axioms.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have a non-measurable set only when you have a sigma-algebra. In particular, for every subset there is a sigma algebra which contains it and the power set is the largest such sigma algebra. And if you take the intersection of all the sigma algebras which contains the set you get the smallest sigma algebra which contains it, also called the sigma algebra generated by it.

Comment: I thought that all subsets of a sigma algebra were by definition measurable; what do you mean by you can only have a non-measurable set only when you have a sigma-algebra

Comment: Measurability is defined with respect to the sigma algebra. So if you have power set as the sigma algebra all subsets will be measurable while at the other extreme if you only have $\{\Omega, \emptyset\}$ as the sigma algebra many sets will be non-measurable

Comment: Then what is meant by a non-measurable set like the Vitali set, does this mean that since the power set of the real numbers contains the vitali set, therefore it is measurable?

Comment: When people say that Vitali set is non measurable, it is with respect to the Lesbegue measure. When the sigma algebra is clear from the context some texts don't mention it

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused then since the Vitali set is an element of its evident sigma algebra, it's measurable then. Or am I not understanding, is it not an element of the evident sigma algebra (which I'm assuming is the power set on the reals)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Power set is not the evident sigma algebra in case of Reals. It is the Lesbegue(or Borel) sigma algebra. And Vitali set is not measurable with respect to this sigma algebra

Comment: Oh, so the Vitali set is not Lesbegue sigma-algebra measurable but then all sets are measurable with respect to the power set of the reals? Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly, that is what I meant.